# Opencart setup multistore on local machine with Xamp

Tags: e-commerce, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3

I've been trying all day to implement a multistore on the opencart platform and I'm not succeeding at all. I followed the instructions on the opencart site but still when I visit another store it shows the same main store.

**What i do:**

1. Base store is located in `D:\xamp-php-8.1\htdocs\opencart-4.0.2.1\upload`
2. I create new vhosts for base store and second store

**Base Store**

```
<VirtualHost base.local>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xamp-php-8.1/htdocs/opencart-4.0.2.1/upload"
    ServerName base.local
    ErrorLog "logs/base.local.log"
    CustomLog "logs/base.local.log" common
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions inherit
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Second store**

```
<VirtualHost second.local>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xamp-php-8.1/htdocs/opencart-4.0.2.1/upload"
    ServerName second.local
</VirtualHost>
```

**Update host file**

```
127.0.0.1 base.local
127.0.0.1 second.local
```

**I change settings by adding new store and set store url to http://second.local/**

For example i create new category and in data tab i check active store for second store but for default unchecked.

Now when i visit `http://base.local/` all works good for base store
When i visit `http://second.local` is its show base store. This need to show new store with new menu items, new logo.

I dont know what i do wrong? Can sombady tell me?

[image: Admin settings]
[image: store1]
[image: store2]

Answer (score 1):

I cant beleve for what i lost 12 hours in my live...

Problem is sloved:

In Store settings in URL you must add `/` at end url....

Cant beleve....